# Existence of a variable in Python 2 vs 3?

Tags: python

Actually I have two questions about the follow code snippets:

Snippet 1:

```
if a:
   return 1
else:
   return 0
```

Snippet 2:

```
try:
    a = input()
except NameError:
   return 0
else:
   return 1
```

These two pieces of code are used to check the existence of a variable in Python. The first was used in Python 3.

My questions are:

1. Why, when given just <kbd>Enter</kbd> is given as input, the first snippet returns `0` which means "does not exist", but in the second snippet of code this is the opposite and it assigns `""` to the value?
2. I'm using Python 2, so for this problem what can I do?

Comment: I cannot understand your question even far enough to try to edit it. Please take the [tour] and review [ask] - a [mcve] that recreates the issue would be very useful.

Comment: None of these snippets check the existence of a variable...

Comment: can you explain me what are these?!

Comment: @Ali.J, just some random pieces of possibly erroneous code, nothing special

Comment: @Ali.J explain *what*?

Comment: @ForceBru OK!you're right!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing the *existence* of a variable and its *value*.

Neither snippet of code directly checks for the existence of the variable named `a`. The first snippets checks its value. If it doesn't exist a `NameError` exception will be raised.

The built-in `input()` function used in snippet 2, is different in Python 2 & 3.

In Python 2 it would implicitly call `eval()` on whatever string of characters was entered by the user—so it *could* raise a `NameError` exception if a reference to an undefined variable was given as input (such as `a` or `b * 42`).

Python 3 doesn't do that. All it does is return whatever the user typed-in as a string (without the trailing newline corresponding to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> the user typed on the keyboard at the end.

The following illustrates how to check for the existence of a variable (and get its value if it exists) in both Python 2 and 3. Note that it's assuming the variable `a` could never have a legal value of `None`.

```
def check_existence_of_a():
    try:
        return a
    except NameError:
        return None

if check_existence_of_a() is None:
    print('variable "a" does not exist')
else:
    print('variable "a" exists and its value is {}'.format(a))

a = 42

if check_existence_of_a() is None:
    print('variable "a" does not exist')
else:
    print('variable "a" exists and its value is {}'.format(a))
```

Output:

```
variable "a" does not exist
variable "a" exists and its value is 42
```

**Update**:

Using Python 2, your second code snippet could be modified as shown below to handle `SyntaxError`s caused by the user typing in nothing but <kbd>Enter</kbd>—which happens because that then causes it to call `eval("")`:

```
def get_a():
    try:
        a = input('>')
    except SyntaxError:
        print('illegal input encountered')  # optional
        return None
    except NameError:
       return 0
    else:
       return 1

get_a()
```

Alternatively, you could switch from using `input()` to `raw_input()`, which does **not** call `eval()` and instead would just return the (possibly empty) `string` the user typed.

Comment: right! I got the difference between input function in python 2 and 3.so what can I do to handle this problem in python 2??I need a condition that if we enter the Enter do somthing and if we enter number or... do something else. :(((

Comment: your snippet code give me this error when I enter the Enter as input: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing                      I think this occur because of the defference between input function in python 2&3

Comment: That's because, as I said, in Python 2, `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`. When you just press Enter, the `raw_input()` portion returns `""`, an empty string, which the `eval` part considers a `SyntaxError`. Try running `eval("")` yourself and see. I will update my answer and show you how to handle it.

Comment: SyntaxError.that's it!